# Запятая перед словом "который": где заканчивается конструкция?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Есть предложение: "***Тот самый парень, который вчера рядом с автобусом тронул её за плечо***".

Где здесь нужны ещё запятые? Перед "который" - это да. А ещё? Можете объяснить, по каким правилам они нужны?

"*рядом с автобусом*" - это уточнение?

Возможен ли такой вариант: "*Тот самый парень, который вчера рядом с автобусом, тронул её за плечо*". Если нет, то почему?
Имеется в виду парень, который именно вчера тронул кого-то за плечо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это СПП с придаточным определительным, союзное слово КОТОРЫЙ, перед ним ставится запятая.

Возможно **авторское обособление внутри придаточного предложения**:

(1) Тот самый парень, который вчера рядом с автобусом тронул её за плечо.

Обстоятельства неоднородные (времени и места), поэтому нет запятых.

(2) Тот самый парень, который **вчера, рядом с автобусом,** тронул её за плечо.

**Авторское уточнение** ситуации при обособлении обстоятельства, указывающего на место действия. Оно представлено как дополнительная,  а не основная информация.

Answer (score 0):

Больше никаких запятых не нужно. Уберем лишнее и посмотрим на базу предложения:

> Тот самый парень, который тронул её за плечо.

"Конструкция", о которой вы говорите, это "который тронул её (за плечо)". А "вчера рядом с автобусом" - уточняющий оборот (специалисты скажут, как он правильно называется) и запятыми он не выделяется.

Comment: Неверное объяснение. Это два обстоятельства: "вчера" и "рядом с автобусом". Одно из них может рассматриваться как уточнение (см. ответ @Jasmin). А уточняющие конструкции обычно выделяются запятыми.

Comment: @М_Г Может рассматриваться, а может и не рассматриваться (см. ответ @Jasmin).

Comment: Согласен: может рассматриваться, а может и не рассматриваться, может обособляться, а может и не обособляться.